# Стеганография через модулирование скорости передачи файлов: есть ли готовые решения?

Tags: стеганография, криптография

«Придумал» новый способ скрыть передачу информации от любопытных и обязывающих законодательно хранить логи в течение 3 месяцев и пр.

А передаёт Б какой-то файл, картинку с котиком. Скорость передачи модулируется: чуть замедляется для передачи "0", становится нормальной, чтобы обозначить "1". Третья сторона снять эту инфу может только если а) знает, что такая передача идёт, б) именно в момент передачи «слушает» канал.

Так вот **вопрос**: наверняка всё уже давно придумано. Не встречались ли вам инструменты, умеющие работать со скоростью приёма/передачи статичных файлов для сокрытия в моменте передачи доп. сообщения? В идеале хотелось бы найти клиентскую часть на JS и серверную в виде модуля nginx.

Для защиты от естественных колебаний скорости, скорее всего, нужно будет одновременно передавать два файла, модулируя их скорость в противоположные стороны, инвертируя и складывая в конце.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то сети TCP/IP работают по другому. Если это не ваша частная сеть с собственными протоколами, то стандартами файл отправляется пакетами. При этом пакеты временем не регламентируются и не могут модулироваться, промежуточные узлы сети могут их задерживать и передавать разными маршрутами по желанию. Поэтому конец файла может придти раньше, чем начало, а сборка завершается только при получение всего файла.

Comment: @Alex Krass TCP вероятно, да. Но тут речь об одном уровне выше: HTTP/1.1 протокол между двумя точками. Файл шлётся в один поток, кусочками. Напр. Ajax обработчик умеет показывать прогресс.

Как крайний случай замедления: можно просто остановить передачу на середине. И передть всего один бит : ) Ну а дальше — вопрос уплотнения и повышения эффективности скрытой передачи.

Comment: Может лучше использовать UDP тогда? С другой стороны, предугадать задержки в общем случае невозможно (см. Теорию телетрафика), можно только для частного случая реализовать.

Comment: @sergiks, протокол HTTP/1.1 основан на протоколе TCP/IP со всеми его недостатками и преимуществами. Просто дополнительные заголовки определяет и поведение TCP/IP для конкретных целей. Ajax умеет показывать прогресс, так как каждый пакет TCP включает заголовок, в котором есть: номер пакета, общее количество байт, количество байт в текущем заголовке. Посчитать полученные проценты и байты тут не составляет труда. Но я не видел, что бы в протоколе был хоть какая-то возможность для подобных действий.

Comment: @Alex Krass, Вы серьезно думаете, что ajax имеет доступ к пакетам с данными TCP?

Там все проще. 

В HTTP-заголовке обычно есть поле `Content-Length`. Вот с ним и сравнивается уже прочитанное количество байт.

Comment: @avp, ну я конечно не имел ввиду, что он прямо напрямую с ними работает. С этим работает браузер, если я не ошибаюсь в иерархии, и предоставляет данные через API уже в JS.